# vmwareのvmxやvmdkをOVFにしたい。

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

vmdkやvmxをOVFに変換したい。
VMware playerやvirtualboxにはvmxでデプロイが出来る事は確認済み。
ovftoolsを使用すると、Error: Failed to open OVF descriptor　というのが出るがこれがなぜ出るのかがよく分からない。

Answer (score 0):

あてずっぽうですが、フルパスで指定すると 上手くいくという情報がありましたので、試してみてください。

[Convert VMDK files to OVF](https://vmarena.blogspot.com/2016/05/convert-vmdk-files-to-ovf.html)

> If you are getting Error: Failed to open OVF descriptor  it is because the path given is not correct .Provide Correct source and destination and start again .
>
> Example.
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware OVF Tool>ovftool C:\VM\virtualmachine.vmx C:\VM\virtualmachine.ovf
>
> ovftool C:\VM\virtumamachine.vmx C:\VM\virtualmachine.ovf
> ```